# Generate a random connected graph with a uniform distribution

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, graph

Are there any C/C++ algorithms / libraries out there that will generate a connected, undirected, unlabeled graph with a uniform distribution?  For example, there are 11,117 undirected, unlabeled, connected graphs with 8 vertices.  I'd like an algorithm that will randomly generate each of these graphs with probability 1/11117.

(Am I correct that the Erdős-Rényi model does not produce a uniform distribution? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model)

Comment: If you don't care about efficiency, you could start with complete graph and randomly delete edges until deletion of any another will cause disconnection.